# Apply Lightning CSS on existing Visualforce pages

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, design

I have a lot of pages with many APEX tags like `<apex:inputText>` or `<apex:outputPanel>`.

I want my application has the Lightning design but without transform all my APEX tags in pure HTML (like shown in Trailheads).

Is there a way to just apply CSS on my tags (with classes for example) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is "no". If you just apply CSS, there are still dependencies on the underlying Standard Stylesheets inherent to the platform that Saleforce changes periodically which that will eventually cause your CSS to break as described in the Trailhead [Visualforce & Lightning Experience Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/lex_dev_visualforce).

Here's the two paragraphs that are particularly relevant from the section titled "Understanding Important Visual Design Considerations":

> Finally, there’s the other approach: adding new rules and styles to your existing (or a new) stylesheet to make your existing markup look more like Lightning Experience. If your page is already mostly styled with your own stylesheets, this approach might work well for you. If instead you’re mostly using the built-in Visualforce components and the Salesforce Classic styling, it requires you to override the styles from the Salesforce Classic stylesheet.
>
> While this is technically possible, we want to discourage you from taking this approach. It introduces dependencies into your markup and styles that you don’t want to have. These dependencies are on the structure, IDs, and classes of the HTML rendered by the built-in Visualforce components. We want to be really clear here: the HTML rendered by the built-in Visualforce components is an internal implementation detail, subject to change without notice. If you have dependencies on it in your own stylesheets, your styling will eventually break.

Comment: Ok, that's what I read too.Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 2):

With winter 18 there is now a lightning style sheet for VF

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_vf_lightningstylesheets.htm

That will do most of the styling automagically

> To style your Visualforce page to match the Lightning Experience UI when viewed in Lightning Experience or the Salesforce1 app, set lightningStylesheets="true" in the  tag. When the page is viewed in Salesforce Classic, it doesn’t get Lightning Experience styling.