# Apply Classic CSS on existing Lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, stylesheets

I saw this question [Apply Lightning CSS on existing Visualforce pages](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128062/apply-lightning-css-on-existing-visualforce-pages)

but i was wondering if the inverse is possible, is there a way to style a lightning component to look like a classic apex pageblock table?

Comment: The short answer to your question is "no".

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 short answers are always best in my opinion!